# How to add a value to a lookup field?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a entitiy "account "in which it has some name_field in Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
Other than lookup field , every other fields values can be inserted. how to select an existing value in look up????

I used the following code to add value to the lookup field.. However I don't get any error..

```
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Attributes["name"] = "Ram"; // this values got inserted
acc.Attributes["age"] = "22"; // this values got inserted
acc.Attributes["lookupfieldid"] = "Sampletext";

service.Create(acc); // to create account
```

How I need to change my code in order to select "primary" value in the lookup field?

Answer (score 10):

Lookup fields in CRM 2011 are `EntityReference`, this means you need to know the `LogicalName` of the entity the lookup is pointing and the `Id` of the record.

so your code wil be:

```
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Attributes["name"] = "Ram"; // this values got inserted
acc.Attributes["age"] = "22"; // this values got inserted

acc.Attributes["lookupfieldid"] = new EntityReference("contact", contactId); // if lookupfieldid is pointing to contact entity

service.Create(acc); // to create account
```

One consideration: you wrote

```
Account acc = new Account();
```

I don't know if you are using early bound (means the classes generated by `crmsvcutil.exe`) or late bound (in this case you will write `Entity acc = new Entity("account");`)

but if you use early bound, the syntax will be something like:

```
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name = "Ram"; // this values got inserted
acc.Age = "22"; // this values got inserted
acc.LookupFieldId = new EntityReference("contact", contactId); // if lookupfieldid is pointing to contact entity
service.Create(acc); // to create account
```

using early bound you will know before the right type expected by the field.

Comment: Thanks for the replay,,
My requirement is to insert default value "Primary" into look up field. It has primary,secondary and other.I need to insert primary while creating account.How can i add value "Primary" into my lookup fields.??

Comment: I'm newbie.. i searched completely everywhere ,but couldnt find it. :( Help me please

Comment: at least post a screenshot to understand which exact field you want to update

Comment: My requirement is to read the contents like name,age,account type(look up field)etc from local sql database  into Dynamic CRM 2011..

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/9mne4hgcj/

screenshot added.if the my db contents says account type is "primary" i want to upload the same content to CRM. How can select the values in lookup field?

Comment: "Type of Account" is a custom field? is a lookup or an optionset(combobox)?

Comment: if it is a lookup you need to use the code I already provided, you need to get the logicalname of entity and the id you want to set.

Answer (score 4):

Based on what you have described, account type is an entity (lets assume it is called new_accounttype) with a name field (new_name) and there are three instances named "Primary", "Secondary" and "Other."  Lookupfieldid is a foreign key that links to the new_accounttype table.  This means that in order to set the account type lookup to "Primary" you need to know the guid of the account type instance where new_name = "Primary".

```
//Retrieve "Primary" account type
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("new_accounttype");
query.Criteria.AddCondition("new_name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "Primary");
Entity accountType = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.First();

//Set the lookup as Guido described above
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Attributes["name"] = "Ram";
acc.Attributes["age"] = "22";
acc.Attributes["lookupfieldid"] = new EntityReference("new_accounttype", accountType.Id);
service.Create(acc);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ..I tried your code.It shows the following exception :-
   An exception System.FormatException was thrown while trying to convert input value 'Primary' to attribute 'new_accounttype.new_name'. Expected type of attribute value: System.Guid. Exception raised: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

Comment: Is new_name a string field on your new_accounttype entity?

Answer (score 0):

**Get Value of Lookup fields**

```
EntityReference entref = (EntityReference)item.Attributes[attributeName];

var LookupId = entref.Id;

var logicalName = entref.LogicalName;
```

**Set Value of Lookup fields**

```
newAccount[attributeName] = new EntityReference(logicalName, LookupId);
```