# inserting value into crm dynamics

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

How can I insert value from Sitecore WFFM forms lookup field to lookup field in CRM Dynamics? I am able to get the value in Guid form from WFFM, but it is not inserting into CRM dynamics. Why??

```
public void Execute(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields, params object[] data)
{
string email = fields.GetValueByFieldID(Email); //this works and insert into CRM
string CountryName = fields.GetValueByFieldID(Country); // this does not work and value is not inserted into the CRM. This one is picking up value in GUID form.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamics CRM:
Lookupfields are EntityReferences.
So you have to set an EntityReference with LogicalName of the Entity and the Id (Guid).

example:

```
Entity entity = new Entity("country");
entity["lookupFieldAttributeName"] = new EntityReference("[PointingToEntityLogicalName]",[PointingToEntity_EntityId(GUID)]);
```

Also there are plenty posts here on SO.

examples:

- [How to add a value to a lookup field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981106/how-to-add-a-value-to-a-lookup-field)
- [Adding value to LOOKUP field in microsoft dynamics crm 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959421/adding-value-to-lookup-field-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011)

Comment: this does not work. Can you explain by changing my code above for country?